# setPristine and setUntouched no working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular js 1.6

```
<div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50">
        <md-input-container class="md-block"> <label>Conduct
            Code</label> <md-select name="ConductCode" ng-model="conductcode"
            style="min-width: 200px;" required> <md-option 
            ng-repeat="val in olCentreFromOtherConduct.conduct" ng-value="val.acadamiccalanderid" ng-bind="val.condcutcode"></md-option>
        </md-select>
        <div ng-messages="CentreFromOtherConductForm.ConductCode.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Please Select Conduct Code</div>
        </div>
        </md-input-container>
</div>
```

When I reset value

```
$scope.Reset = function () {
        $scope.conductcode = 0;
}
```

then its state should be untouch !! I have tried different following things , but nothing is working

```
//          $scope.CentreFromOtherConductForm.ConductCode.$touched = true;
//          $scope.CentreFromOtherConductForm.ConductCode.$valid = true;
//          $scope.CentreFromOtherConductForm.ConductCode.$invalid = false;
//          $scope.CentreFromOtherConductForm.ConductCode.$setUntouched();
```

OR

```
angular.forEach($scope.CentreFromOtherConductForm, function (input) {
            if (input && input.hasOwnProperty('$viewValue')) {
              input.$setPristine();
              input.$setUntouched();
            }
});
```

any update !!!

Comment: Is ConductCode the form name? It looks like it isn't. Also, $setPristine() is used on the form not on inputs.

Comment: `CentreFromOtherConductForm` form name and `ConductCode` is element name `md-select name="ConductCode"` @rrd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to call the methods on the form, not on the inputs:

```
$scope.CentreFromOtherConductForm.$setPristine();
$scope.CentreFromOtherConductForm.$setUntouched();
```